# Anyone know what libChineseTokenizer.dylib is?

Tags: library

I found it in:

`/usr/lib/libChineseTokenizer.dylib`

It looks like it was installed as part of an update, but want to be sure it's legit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is found in the standard install of macOS - I have it also on my machines. So the file name itself is legit - ofcourse the content of your specific file might be malicious, but nothing indicates that.

The purpose of the file is to implement a "tokenizer", which is a computer program that takes a long text string (such as this answer), and splits it up into its parts (tokens). This particular file implements that for Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard part of macOS. It's supposed to be there.